# Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/(\langle(a,0)\rangle \times \langle(0,b)\rangle)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_a \oplus \mathbb{Z}_b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

[image]

I understand how to prove the homomorphism is in fact a homomorphism. I am confused on why the kernel is denoted $(\langle(a,0)\rangle \times \langle(0,b)\rangle)$. It could be a notation confusion? I understan why $x=na$ and $y=mb$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. How does this imply the kernel is what it is?

Answer (score 0):

If $(n, k) \in \mathbb{Z}$ maps to $(0, 0)$, then $n = 0 \operatorname{mod}(a)$ and $k = 0 \operatorname{mod}(b)$.  So $n = ax$ and $k = by$.  Further
$$
(n, k) = (ax, by) = (ax, 0) + (0, by).
$$
Thus the kernel is generated by $(a, 0)$ and $(0, b)$.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. thank you for clarifying!